# Cron Job to Schedule Rails Website Going Live?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, cron

I'm currently building a website for an awesome youth church we run (shameless plug!)..

Anywho at the moment we have a static countdown page http://mybase.co , and were having a massive launch this weekend and the site needs to go live when we launch,

it's a rails app..

How would you recommend scheduling it going live?

having a cron job and an apache a2en?

or is there a better way?

Thanks

Daniel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about putting your countdown in an index.html and using a cron job (or similar) to delete it.

And have a `:before_filter` in your application controller that does a

```
redirect_to root_path unless Time.now > launch_time
```

Naturally, sometime after you launch, you'll want to remove the `:before_filter`...

Answer (score 1):

Try https://github.com/javan/whenever for cron jobs in ruby

Answer (score 0):

Have a look into [at](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?at) jobs. It makes more sense than cron. As cron jobs will recur.

Answer (score 0):

No need for cron jobs:

```
before_filter :countdown

protected
def countdown
  render(:template => '/timeout') if Time.now < "01/13/2011".to_time
end
```